# local_costmap "ghost objects"; Restarting move_base

Tags: ros, navigation, roslaunch, local-costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey all,

I am running the ROS naviagation stack with a 360 degree lidar. After running a couple paths. the local costmap from the lidar seems to fill up with "ghost objects" until the robot can no longer generate a path to the destination. I looked for methods to clear or reset to local costmap, but didn't find much on it, so my new approach is to restart the move_base node.

I want to restart the move_base node from where I send the action_lib goal, so that the local_costmap can restart. I found [this](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/API%20Usage); however I have not found out how to set parameters for the node. I also would prefer not to write the path to the `.launch` file (the second example) to avoid having to manually write the path on each new robot/system.

TLDR; Is there a method to clear the local costmap? Or is there a good way to restart the move_base node programmatically from where I send an actionlib goal?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267485/local_costmap-%22ghost-objects%22;-restarting-move_base/) by [xnick77x](https://answers.ros.org/users/30994/xnick77x/) on ROS Answers with karma: 77 on 2017-07-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, there are better ways to clear the costmaps. From the command line you can:

```
rosservice call /move_base/clear_costmaps
```

And you can also call servcies from your code, as explained [here](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient%28c%2B%2B%29).

I also suggest you create **another** question with more details about the "ghost objects", with images and your costmap configurations, so maybe you can address the origin of your problem.

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2017-07-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [parzival](https://answers.ros.org/users/35453/parzival/) on 2021-04-06**:
Hi, does this clear both costmaps? Or only the local costmap?
I think even if it clears both, the global costmap upon reinflation would be identical to previous one, so effectively only the local costmap would be reset. Do you think this is true?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For anyone looking how to do this via c++, here you go:

```
std_srvs::Empty emptymsg;
ros::service::call("/move_base/clear_costmaps",emptymsg);
```

---

Originally posted by [biglotusturtle](https://answers.ros.org/users/30307/biglotusturtle/) with karma: 165 on 2017-11-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2